# After upgrade to Ubuntu 13.10 bluetooth mouse not working when waking up from suspend, how can it be solved?

Tags: mouse, bluetooth, suspend

As the topic says, While using Ubuntu 13.04 I had no problem and when the computer woke up from suspend mode the mouse would work automatically without me doing anything.
Since the upgrade to 13.10 I need to manually go to the bluetooth icon in the panel, select the mouse and click the `connection` again even though it's marked as operating.
Any idea how to solve this issue?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In my case I fixed adding this script:

/etc/pm/sleep.d/20_bluetooth

```
#!/bin/bash

case $1 in
    suspend|hibernate|suspend_hybrid)
      rfkill block bluetooth
    ;;
    resume|thaw)
      rfkill block bluetooth
      rfkill unblock bluetooth
    ;;
    *)
    ;;
esac

exit
```

And then:

```
chmod +x /etc/pm/sleep.d/20_bluetooth
```

Comment: I did it but it doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

This is still a problem even in 14.04. The bluetooth driver stays stale so you need to remove and re-add the module, then all works fine. Bellow is what you need:

```
sudo vi /etc/pm/sleep.d/10_bluetooth
```

(use text editor of your choice) and insert:

```
#!/bin/bash
#Code from http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1387211

. /usr/lib/pm-utils/functions

case "$1" in
    hibernate|suspend)
    rfkill block bluetooth
    ;;
    thaw|resume)  #!/bin/bash
#Code from http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1387211

. /usr/l
    rfkill unblock bluetooth
    rmmod btusb
    modprobe btusb
    ;;
    *)
    ;;
esac

exit
```

Save and chmod to executable:

```
chmod 755 /etc/pm/sleep.d/10_bluetooth
```